# Updating state of array index in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use an interval to update my state to the next array index, but it has been a struggle. Can anyone help?

```
    arrayCount() {
     let count = 0;
     let sliced = this.state.data.slice();
      this.setState({
       data: sliced[count++],
      })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
     let timer = setInterval(this.arrayCount, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Add this this.arrayCount.bind(this) in the setInterval method

Comment: What is your initial `data` state ? Your arrayCount function will replace the data state by `data[0]` each time (this means on second tick `initialData[newdata[0]]` ...)

Comment: My data just for the testing is this: data: [‘a’, 2, 3]

Comment: How would i get it to just go to the next index? Thats my problem

Answer (score 1):

You are not binding `arrayCount` to correct context. Try this

```
arrayCount() {
  let count = 0;
  let sliced = this.state.data.slice();
  this.setState({
    data: sliced[count++],
  })
}

componentDidMount() {
  let timer = setInterval(this.arrayCount.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Comment: One of the things I don't like in React is how often we need to explicitly bind `this` to a function before passing them around.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Well in this specific case it's pure JS nuance, so not React fault..

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can achieve what you want, as other mentioned you are forgetting that `arrayCount` doesn't know what you are referring to with `this`. You need to explicitly provide it or it will grab it from its own scope. In React there are two ways you usually do this, in the constructor:

```
class MyComponent extends Componenet {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.arrayCount = this.arrayCount.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let timer = setInterval(this.arrayCount, 1000);
  }

  arrayCount() {
    let count = 0;
    let sliced = this.state.data.slice();
    this.setState({
      data: sliced[count++],
    });
  }
  ...
```

This will avoid that you have to do `.bind(this)` every time you want to use that method.

Another approach (if you enabled such syntax in your config), is less verbose and all you need to do is:

```
class MyComponent extends Componenet {
  componentDidMount() {
    let timer = setInterval(this.arrayCount, 1000);
  }

  arrayCount = () => {
    let count = 0;
    let sliced = this.state.data.slice();
    this.setState({
      data: sliced[count++],
    });
  }
  ...
```

As you will notice the `arrayCount` has been made into an arrow function which doesn't create a new context from where it grabs `this`. This means that now `this` is grabbed from the outer scope which in this case is the `MyComponent` class.